# Proxmox Failed all of a sudden mentioning that CPU was blocked for more than 25s

Tags: proxmox

I'm a beginner in Proxmox.

Actually, everything was working perfectly fine until I installed 2 additional hard disks in my server.

All of a sudden, I had an error mentioning that CPU was blocked for more then 25sec... I restarted and the server and now it's telling me that I'm in Emergency Mode...

I have 2 options:

- Give root password for maintenance
- press Control-D to continue

Control-D:
When I'm pressing control-D to continue it's saying: Reloading system manager configuration, starting default target. Then it starts asking the password for maintenance or press control-d... again and again...

Root Password
Is is the same password as the one I'm using to connect to the GUI? If that's the case, since I have a very long password with special characters, I need to see what I'm typing which is not the case by default... How can I check that?

What if I remove the 2 new additional hard disks ? Should it start normally ? Or I will still be in emergency mode ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same password and no, you cannot see what you are typing.

Remove drives, it should boot normally. You need to check and edit /etc/fstab so it's not using new drives as root. Maybe these two disks are not empty?